# Can I use "such as" after em-dash?

Tags: em-dashes

Example:

> So you might need help from various resources—such as parents, classmates, school administrators, and so on.

Or should I write:

> So you might need help from various resources—parents, classmates, school administrators, and so on.

Comment: 'Such as' and 'and so on' are doing the same job, and this tautology has no redeeming features.

Comment: Doesn't the em-dash basically replace the "such as" in that sentence?

Comment: You could also use a colon to introduce a list.

Comment: Your second version sounds much more like what a yeoman writer would write.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this website for the correct usage of "such as"](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/such-as-comma/)

It is better not use dash before "such as", you can use a comma if needed(Check the website above),
[So you might need help from various resources, such as parents , classmates, school administrators, and so on.]